# Why is my code printing the wrong total?

Tags: java

Why when you lose money does my code replace the lost amount for the total amount? I'm not sure if the error is in one of the functions or in the main.

Example output with bad replacement:

```
You have 100 dollars.
Enter an amount to bet (0 to quit):56
High, low or sevens (H/L/S):l
Die 1 rolls: 4
Die 2 rolls: 5
Total of two dice is: 9
You lost!
You have 56 dollars.
Enter an amount to bet (0 to quit):
```

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Project07 {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Fill in the body
        int totalAmount = 100;
        while(totalAmount>0){
        boolean b = true;
        boolean c = true;
        int dollars = 100;
        Scanner inScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("You have "+totalAmount+" dollars.");
        while (b){
        dollars = getBet(inScanner, dollars);
        if(dollars>0 && dollars<100){
            b=false;
        }
        }
        char sevensHL = getHighLow(inScanner);
        while(sevensHL == 'q'){
            System.out.println("ERROR! Enter H,L, or S.");
            sevensHL = getHighLow(inScanner);
        }
        int die1 = getRoll();
        int die2 = getRoll();
        System.out.println("Die 1 rolls: " + die1);
        System.out.println("Die 2 rolls: " + die2);
        int total = die1 + die2;
        System.out.println("Total of two dice is: " + total);
        int winnings = determineWinnings(sevensHL, dollars, total);
        totalAmount = totalAmount + winnings; 
        }
        System.out.println("You have 0 dollars left");
        System.out.print("Goodbye!");
    }


    // Given a Scanner and a current maximum amount of money, prompt the user for
    // an integer representing the number of dollars that they want to bet.  This
    // number must be between 0 and to maximum number of dollars.  If the user enters
    // a number that is out of bounds, display an error message and ask again.
    // Return the bet to the calling program.
    private static int getBet(Scanner inScanner, int currentPool) {
        // Fill in the body
        int wager;

        System.out.print("Enter an amount to bet (0 to quit):");
        wager = inScanner.nextInt();
        if(wager == 0){
            System.out.println("You have "+ currentPool +" left");
            System.out.print("Goodbye!");
            System.exit(0);
            return 0; 
        }
        else if(wager<0 || wager>100){
            System.out.println("Your bet MUST be between 0 and 100 dollars");
            wager = 0;
            int currentDollars=currentPool - wager;
            return currentDollars;
        }
        else{
            int currentDollars=currentPool - wager;
            return currentDollars;
        }

    }

    // Given a Scanner, prompt the user for a single character indicating whether they
    // would like to bet High ('H'), Low ('L') or Sevens ('S').  Your code should accept
    // either capital or lowercase answers, but should display an error if the user attempts
    // to enter anything but one of these 3 values and prompt for a valid answer.
    // Return the character to the calling program.
    private static char getHighLow(Scanner inScanner) {
        // Fill in the body

        System.out.print("High, low or sevens (H/L/S):");
        String input = inScanner.next();

        if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("h")){
            char out = 'h';
            return out;
        }
        else if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("l")){
            char out = 'l';
            return out;
        }
        else if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("s")){
            char out = 's';
            return out;
        }
        else{
            return 'q';
        }


    }

    // Produce a random roll of a single six-sided die and return that value to the calling
    // program
    private static int getRoll() {
        // Fill in the body

         int die = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * ((6 - 1) + 1));
         return die;
    }

    // Given the choice of high, low or sevens, the player's bet and the total result of
    // the roll of the dice, determine how much the player has won.  If the player loses
    // the bet then winnings should be negative.  If the player wins, the winnings should
    // be equal to the bet if the choice is High or Low and 4 times the bet if the choice
    // was Sevens.  Return the winnings to the calling program.
    private static int determineWinnings(char highLow, int bet, int roll) {
        // Fill in the body
        if (highLow == 'h' && roll >=8){
            int payout = bet;
            System.out.println("You won " + payout +" dollars!");
            return payout;
        }
        else if(highLow == 'l' && roll <= 6){
            int payout = bet;
            System.out.println("You won " + payout +" dollars!");
            return payout;
        }
        else if(highLow == 's' && roll == 7){
            int payout = 4*bet;
            System.out.println("You won " + payout +" dollars!");
            return payout;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("You lost!");
            int payout = (-1)*bet;
            return payout;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you stepped through your code in a debugger?

Comment: We'd expect he'd have done that before coming here, right?

Comment: Because `getBet()` is wrong

Answer (score 0):

We seem to be deducting the bet from remaining amount in `getBet()` method itself. That, combined with addition of win/loss results in incorrect amount.

We need to change `getBet()` method as follows:

```
private static int getBet(Scanner inScanner, int currentPool) {
    // Fill in the body
    int wager;

    System.out.print("Enter an amount to bet (0 to quit):");
    wager = inScanner.nextInt();
    if(wager == 0){
        System.out.println("You have "+ currentPool +" left");
        System.out.print("Goodbye!");
        System.exit(0);
        return 0; 
    }
    else if(wager<0 || wager>100){
        System.out.println("Your bet MUST be between 0 and 100 dollars");
        wager = 0;
        return wager;
    }
    else{
        return wager;
    }

}
```

Also, instead of passing `dollars` in `getBet()` call, we need to pass `totalDollars` as that is the correct amount. So, change:

`dollars = getBet(inScanner, dollars);`

to

`dollars = getBet(inScanner, totalAmount);`

It should show correct total after making these changes.